# É correto usar @MappedSuperclass em vez de @Entity para não criar uma tabela no banco de dados usando JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

Explicando o problema, preciso consultar uma função no POSTGRES:

```
SELECT * from pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid AS id, source, target, length AS cost FROM ways', 11111, 22222);
```

O "pgr_dijkstra" é uma função do POSTGIS, e não uma tabela. Me retorna o menor caminho entre o "source"(11111) e o "target(2222)". O resultado são 6 colunas: "seq, path_seq, node, edge, cost e agg_cost".

Por "pgr_dijkstra" ser uma função eu não posso simplesmente criar uma classe no meu código e anotar ela com @Entity, acrescentando também @Id para "seq" e criar os demais 5 campos (path_seq, node, edge, cost e agg_cost). Isso criaria uma nova tabela no banco de dados. Após pesquisar muito, achei uma solução que acredito estar longe do ideal, que não seria boa prática. OBS: Estou usando Spring Boot + Java. O valor do "source" e "target" não serão fixos, os usuários irão enviar via browser, coloquei fixo somente para testar essa parte mais rapidamente.

#### Classe POJO

```
public class Dijkstra3 {

    public Integer seq;
    public Integer path_seq;
    public BigInteger node;
    public BigInteger edge;
    public double cost;
    public double agg_cost;

    public Dijkstra3(Integer seq, Integer path_seq, BigInteger node, BigInteger edge, double cost, double agg_cost) {
        super();
        this.seq = seq;
        this.path_seq = path_seq;
        this.node = node;
        this.edge = edge;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.agg_cost = agg_cost;
    }

    //GETTERS ...

}
```

#### Mapeamento da consulta

Classe abstrata com o meu @SqlResultSetMapping e @NamedNativeQuery. A anotação @SqlResultSetMapping está mapeando o resultando  para Dijkstra3.class, que é meu POJO. @NamedNativeQuery é minha query, que vou usar, nela aponto para o mapeamento "DijkstraMapping". Eu anotei a classe com @MappedSuperclass, se eu não fizesse isso teria que anotar com @Entity e uma nova tabela no banco de dados seria criada.

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "DijkstraMapping",
    classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(
            columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name="seq", type=Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="path_seq", type=Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="node", type=BigInteger.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="edge", type=BigInteger.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="cost", type=Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="agg_cost", type=Double.class)
            },
            targetClass = Dijkstra3.class
        )
    }
)

@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
         name = "GetDijkstra",
         query = "SELECT * from pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid AS id, source, target, length AS cost FROM ways', 11111, 22222)",
          resultSetMapping = "DijkstraMapping"
    )
}) 

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class DijkstraSqlMap{

}
```

#### Repository

```
@Repository
public class TestRepository2 {      

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public List<Dijkstra3> callDijkstra(){
  
        TypedQuery<Dijkstra3> query = em.createNamedQuery("GetDijkstra", Dijkstra3.class);
        List<Dijkstra3> lista = query.getResultList();

        return lista;
    }
}
```

#### Controller ou Service:

```
@Autowired
TestRepository2 testeRepository2;

...

List<Dijkstra3> callHelloWorld = testeRepository2.callDijkstra();

...
```

Isso funciona. Após pesquisar e testar tudo o que encontrei, essa foi a melhor forma que encontrei de se pegar o resultado de uma query utilizando JPA, passar os dados para um objeto / POJO, e principalmente NÃO CRIAR UMA NOVA TABELA NO BANCO DE DADOS, pois "pgr_dijkstra" é uma função e os seus dados de retorno não representam uma tabela.

É correto anotar a classe DijkstraSqlMap com @MappedSuperclass para apenas não precisar anotar com @Entity? Existe alguma outra melhor maneira de pegar o resultado de uma consulta no banco de dados e passar para um objeto / POJO sem criar uma nova tabela no banco? Agradeço o tempo e ajuda de vocês.

Comment: Olha, eu não domino JPA mas já usei `@MappedSuperclass`, sei que ela omite a criação da tabela se não for uma `@Entity` (mas tiver subclasses `@Entity`s). Só que a meu ver o objetivo dela é permitir mapear herança de classes (comportamento e dados reusáveis isolados em uma abstração) p/ o modelo relacional quando você não tem necessidade de persistir em uma "tabela-pai", vejo isso pelo próprio nome da annotation, e entendo que não é para isso que você está usando. Eu não entendi bem a relação entre a `@MappedSuperclass` e a query nativa/named que você está chamando, então não sei opinar mais.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correto é relativo nesse caso. Você está lidando com uma limitação do JPA - o fato de anotações `@NamedNativeQuery` e `@SqlResultSetMapping` precisarem estar atreladas a alguma entidade para que o JPA consiga encontrá-las. Seu código funciona, mas realmente é estranho criar uma superclasse mapeada só para ter algum lugar para estacionar sua *named query*.

É claro que existem alternativas para o uso de `@MappedSuperclass`. Cada uma com seu prós e contras.

#### 1. "Emprestar" o escopo de alguma outra entidade relacionada ao problema.

Como `Dijkstra3` é um POJO simples você não pode mover a *named query* para essa classe. Dito isso, talvez você tenha alguma entidade relacionada. Por exemplo, talvez a sua tabela *ways* esteja mapeada para uma entidade `Way` no seu código. Como no fundo essa é uma consulta indireta a tabela *ways*, eu não veria nenhum problema em definir a consulta no topo dessa entidade.

#### 2. Mover a query para um arquivo XML

Essa também é uma opção, por exemplo, usando `META-INF/orm.xml`:

```
<named-native-query name="GetDijkstra" result-set-mapping="DijkstraMapping">
    <query>SELECT * from pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid AS id, source, target, length AS cost FROM ways', 11111, 22222)</query>
</named-native-query>

<sql-result-set-mapping name="DijkstraMapping">
    <constructor-result target-class="meu.pacote.Dijkstra3">
        <column name="seq" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <column name="path_seq" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <column name="node" class="java.math.BigInteger"/>
        <column name="edge" class="java.math.BigInteger"/>
        <column name="seq" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <column name="path_seq" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    </constructor-result>
</sql-result-set-mapping>
```

#### 3. Fazer a sua consulta diretamente

Você não precisa definir uma *named query*, como você tem acesso direto ao *EntityManager* basta fazer a consulta com o SQL. Por exemplo, chamando os métodos [`createNativeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-) ou [`createStoredProcedureQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createStoredProcedureQuery-java.lang.String-) no seu repositório.

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * from pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid AS id, source, target, length AS cost FROM ways', 11111, 22222)", "DijkstraMapping");
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Dijkstra3> lista = query.getResultList();
```

É claro que nesse caso `DijkstraMapping` precisa ter sido definido em algum lugar. Alternativamente você pode não usar o *mapping* e mapear a o resultado (`List<Object[]>`) manualmente ou utilizando uma biblioteca como [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/).

#### 4. Query nativa + `ResultTransformer` do Hibernate

Conforme [esse artigo do Vlad Mihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) também é possível usar um `ResultTransformer` do Hibernate ara retornar um DTO da *query* nativa (veja também [documentação oficial](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-dto-query)):

```
List<Dijkstra3> distances = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * from pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid AS id, source, target, length AS cost FROM ways', 11111, 22222)")
    .unwrap(org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery.class)
    .setResultTransformer(
        Transformers.aliasToBean(Dijkstra3.class))
    .getResultList();
```

O método [`setResultTransformer`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setResultTransformer-org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer-) foi marcado como *deprecated* na versão 5.2 do Hibernate, porém, conforme [outro artigo do Vlad](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-resulttransformer/), por enquanto você ainda tem que usar esse método, já que s alternativa com `@FunctionInterface` só estará disponível no Hibernate 6.

#### 5. Abusar do `@Subselect`

Outra opção do Hibernate é a anotação [`@Subselect`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Subselect.html). O propósito da anotação é fazer com que `Dijkstra3` esteja ligado a uma *query* ao invés de uma tabela.

```
@Entity
@Subselect("SELECT * from pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid AS id, source, target, length AS cost FROM ways', 11111, 22222)")
@Synchronize({ "ways" })
public class Dijkstra3 { // ... }
```

Dito isso, desconheço uma boa maneira de passar parâmetros dinamicamente para essa consulta.

#### 6. Usar uma biblioteca em cima do JPA

Como você percebeu o JPA tem suas limitações e já está mostrando sua idade. A última versão do JPA (2.2) é de 2017. Desejo toda a sorte do mundo para o projeto [Jakarta EE](https://jakarta.ee/), e não quero ser injusto (migrar o projeto está sendo um esforço descomunal), mas até agora o foco foi *rebranding* e *renaming* de pacotes (o [Jakarta Persistence 3.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/) é basicamente o JPA 2.2 em outro pacote). Quem sabe o Jakarta EE 10 não trará algumas novidades para a especificação de persistência.

**Spring Data**

Enquanto isso *libraries* como [Spring Data](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data) vão ganhando espaço. Como você já está usando Spring talvez valha a pena considerar algo assim.
Com Spring Data JPA, por exemplo, você pode combinar a anotação [`@Query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) com [projeções](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) para fazer o que você precisa (Para mais detalhes, veja [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48296588/664577) do usuário [Michal Stochmal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7974082/micha%C5%82-stochmal) no Stack Overflow em inglês):

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * from pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid AS id, source, target, length AS cost FROM ways', ?1, ?2)", nativeQuery = true)
List<Dijkstra3> callDijkstra(int source, int target);
```

Porém você ainda precisará ter uma entidade para o *Repositório* bem como fazer com que as colunas de consulta batam com a projeção.

**Outras opções**

Em algumas situações talvez compense tirar o JPA e o Hibernate da jogada. Você pode sempre trabalhar com uma abstração em cima do JDBC como o [Spring Data JDBC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#reference), [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/) ou [JDBI](https://jdbi.org/). Eu admito que apesar de ter criado a *tag* [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate) aqui no Stack Overflow em Português, hoje em dia quando a escolha tecnológica cabe a mim eu dificilmente parto diretamente para um ORM.

Comment: Obrigado Anthony. Eu fiz + um teste com a opção do ResultTransformer do Hibernate. Funcionou perfeitamente, e achei melhor porque eu pude excluir minha classe "ways" anotada com Entity, não necessito dessa classe no projeto. Sou iniciante e leio muito sobre programar baseado na especificação, e não em uma implementação como Hibernate. Mas nesse caso não vejo problema algum, é um recurso que ele oferece e que serve perfeitamente para o meu problema, e q até mesmo o Vlad sugere usar no artigo que você citou. Anotarei com deprecated e //TODO até o Hibernate 6 aparecer com o @FunctionInterface.

Comment: Glad to be of service. Estou apagando meus comentários aqui para não bagunçar o post. Quando tiver com tempo traduzo minha resposta para o seu crosspost no SOen.